# Adding foreign key to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a DigitalOcean LAMP instance to do my homework for class, however scripts that run on the lab machines error on my server when trying to add foreign keys.

```
--------------
create table STATE (
statecode   char(2),
description varchar(30) NOT NULL,
constraint state_statecode_pk primary key (statecode))
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

--------------
create table EMPLOYER (
companyname     varchar(30) NOT NULL,
division        varchar(30) NOT NULL,
address         varchar(30),
city            varchar(20),
statecode       char(2) not null,
zipcode         int(5),
constraint employer_coname_div_pk PRIMARY KEY (companyname, division),
constraint employer_statecode_fk foreign key (statecode) references state(statecode))

--------------

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

What kind of differences could cause it to not work on my machine, but work on the lab machines?

version on my computer: 5.6.19
version on lab machine: 5.6.21

show create table employer from lab machine:

```
| employer | CREATE TABLE `employer` (
  `companyname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statecode` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`companyname`,`division`),
  KEY `employer_statecode_fk` (`statecode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employer_statecode_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`statecode`) REFERENCES `state` (`statecode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

They're both InnoDB. The lab machine charset is utf8 while the server is latin1, but that shouldn't cause an error with creating the constraint.

Comment: Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements please. On the lab machines, you may be creating a MyISAM engine table, while on your server you're getting an InnoDB table - MyISAM doesn't actually enforce FKs, so the creation may work even though the FK can't be used.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code you have here - the main reasons for 1215 are a data type mismatch between the parent and child column - yours are both `char(2)` - or a lack of index on the parent - yours is a PK, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, your create statements do work with MySQL 5.6 using InnoDB as well as MyISAM: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a383

Answer (score 0):

Please check the engine of the database table on different machines . For foreign key constraints InnoDB is supported.
ENGINE=InnoDB should show up in "show create table tablename"

Database schema should be created like :

create table STATE (
statecode   char(2),
description varchar(30) NOT NULL,
constraint state_statecode_pk primary key (statecode)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 0):

Since the case sensitivity depends on the machine's filesystem, the tables of the lab machine (windows) were case insensitive, where the tables on the server (ubuntu) were case sensitive.

Because of this, referencing the sales table on Windows or OS X works because SALES and sales both reference the same table, where as on Ubuntu the table sales doesn't exist, and you can't make a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist.